# What the Parameter..?

Tags: forms, authentication, parameters, instance

I want to ask what is the parameter content of this code

static frmMain _instance;

```
    public frmMain(string userInfo)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        btnUserInfo.Text = userInfo;
        //this.StyleManager = metroStyleManager1;
    }

    public static frmMain Instance
    {
        get
        {
            if (_instance == null)
            **_instance = new frmMain(*//What's in here//*);**
            return _instance;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Have you searched? I guarantee you if you look up what a parameter is you'd have your answer.

Comment: I know the parameters is frmMain(string userInfo) but When I enter
            _instance = new frmMain(userInfo); or _instance = new frmMain(txtUser.text); still Error

Comment: I try to add "public frmMain (){ }". Does it matter?

Comment: You haven't said what errors you're getting, so it's difficult for anyone to help you.